# How to add Skype information to contact structured data?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have these structured data for my contact page:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://mysupersite.net/",
    "logo": "https://mysupersite.net/mysuperlogo.png",
    "contactPoint": [{
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "telephone": "+7 (495) 509-61-20",
        "email": "some@email.net",
        "contactType": "customer service"
    }]
}
</script>
```

How can I add information about my Skype contact here?

Comment: As I’m not familiar with Skype, how would such a Skype contact look like?

Comment: Somthing like: "skype:SkypeUser?add" or just "skype:SkypeUser"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put Skype under [Social Links](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links) not under Phone Contact.
Phone contacts extract the real phone number. Skype is a Link. Use `skype://myskypelink`

Comment: Thank you very much Lovnola! I was sinking of it as a contact, not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

For Skype (and similar usecases like WhatsApp, Signal and other messaging services), you could create a dedicated `ContactPoint` for each. According to the [ContactPoint schema documentation](https://schema.org/ContactPoint), you can put the handle into `identifier` and use `contactType` and / or `description` to tell what this contact point is about:

```json
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://mysupersite.net/",
    "logo": "https://mysupersite.net/mysuperlogo.png",
    "contactPoint": [
      {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "contactType": "customer service",
        "telephone": "+7 (495) 509-61-20",
        "email": "some@email.net"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "contactType": "customer service (Skype)",
        "identifier": "YourSkypeUserName",
        "url": "skype:YourSkypeUserName?call"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "contactType": "customer service (WhatsApp)",
        "identifier": "+74955096120"
      }
    ]
}
</script>
```

As seen with the Skype contact, where available, where available URLs should be provided that represent the contact point information (see: [Skype URI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference)). The code above can be further enhanced by using an identifier of type [`PropertyValue`](https://schema.org/PropertyValue) ([example](https://schema.org/identifier#eg-0373)).